# Move Files using batch in a subdirectory

Tags: windows, batch-file

Update: Solved.

I'm trying to move all files  except two ("Item.bat" and "item.csv") from any folder or directory that the user is in to another predefined folder. Would i be able to do this?

Thank you.

I have tried the following

```
 for %%i in (*.*) do if not "%%~nxi"=="ItemMaster.csv" if not "%%~nxi"=="ItemMaster.bat" move /-y "%%i" "%userprofile%\desktop\testmove"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all the files, then move "Item.bat" and "item.csv" back to their original location.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. I was missing the destination folder.

```
for %%i in (*.*) do if not "%%~nxi"=="ItemMaster.csv" if not "%%~nxi"=="ItemMaster.bat" move /-y "%%i" "%userprofile%\desktop\testmove"
```